# (Oracle)Correlated subquery usage

Tags: oracle, subquery, window-functions, correlated-subquery, ora-00904

Subquery query1 below works fine.
But when I put equi condition in -sort of- nested clause like query2, it shows error ORA-00904.
Is  this  wrong usage of correlated subquery or it is because of other reason?

```
--Query1: It shows expected result.

    SELECT
    O.ENAME
    O,SAL
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM SCOTT.EMP I
        WHERE I.SAL>O.SAL  --correlated to outer
     ) AS RESULT
    from SCOTT.EMP O;


--Query2:ORA-00904: "O"."SAL": invalid identifier shows. How to modify to use correlated subquery?

    SELECT
    O.ENAME
    O,SAL
    ,(
    WITH TEMP AS 
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM SCOTT.EMP I
        WHERE I.SAL>O.SAL   --I have put equi condistion here 
        )
    SELECT * FROM TEMP
    )  AS RESULT
    from SCOTT.EMP O;
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? There was a one-level limit in parent/child references until 12.1 (I think); but not sure how that works with CTEs in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second option is a wrong use of correlated subqueries, not because of the comparison, but for the use of the with clause. **I would like to remember that you should avoid correlated subqueries as much as possible**.

The WITH clause, or subquery factoring clause, may be processed as an inline view or resolved as a temporary table. The advantage of the latter is that repeated references to the subquery may be more efficient as the data is easily retrieved from the temporary table, rather than being requeried by each reference.

In your third column of your second query you want to get the result from the inline view. The problem is that parsing of the inline view is done independently and therefore cannot have references to anything in the outer query.

```
SQL> create table emp ( ename varchar2(10) , sal number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into emp values ( 'AAA' , 1000 ) ;

insert into emp values ( 'BBB' , 1000 ) ;

insert into emp values ( 'CCC' , 1000 ) ;

insert into emp values ( 'DDD' , 1000 ) ;
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>

1 row created.

SQL> select * from emp ;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
AAA              1000
BBB              1000
CCC              1000
DDD              1000
```

To write the query with inline view, the filter must be done in the outer query

```
SELECT
    O.ENAME
    O,SAL
    ,(
    WITH TEMP AS 
        (
        SELECT * FROM EMP 
        )
    SELECT count(*) FROM TEMP t WHERE t.SAL>O.SAL
    )  AS RESULT
    from EMP O;
O                 SAL     RESULT
---------- ---------- ----------
AAA              1000          0
BBB              1000          0
CCC              1000          0
DDD              1000          0
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been explained that the second query does not uses `with` correctly.

Let me suggest, however, that your query can be simpler and more efficiently phrased. For each employee, you want to count how many employees have a greater salary. Window functions are the way to go here:

```
select e.*, rank() over(order by salary desc) - 1 result
from scott.emp e
```